# Onclick event to put an image from a table to another table. Javascript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two tables. One table contains several images and the other one is empty.
What I want is that clicking on one of the images from the first table will take that image and put it on the other table enlarging its size.

This is how my tables look like:

```
<div>
        <table id="enlarged" width="530px" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Enlarged Picture.</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="div1"> </div>
                </td>
            </tr>   
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div>
        <table id="small" width="530px" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Click on picture to see it enlarged.</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img id="picture1" src="winter.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; align:left;" onclick="addPictureToTable();">
                    <img id="picture2" src="winter1.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; align:left;" onclick="addPictureToTable();">
                    <img id="picture3" src="winter2.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; align:left;" onclick="addPictureToTable();">
                    <img id="picture4" src="winter3.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; align:left;" onclick="addPictureToTable();">
                    <img id="picture5" src="winter4.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; align:left;" onclick="addPictureToTable();">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

What i've tried:

```
function addPictureToTable(){

            var myPicture = document.getElementById("picture1");
            var table = document.getElementById("enlarged");

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= myPicture;

        }
```

If it helps, my pictures taken from the first table can be put into a simple div, not needing the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I should ask, what is the issue that you are having with your current code?
Second, I would suggest making the elementID be a parameter to your addPictureToTable function, so that:

```
<img id="picture1" src="winter.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; align:left;" onclick="addPictureToTable();">
```

becomes:

```
<img id="picture1" src="winter.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; align:left;" onclick="addPictureToTable("picture1");">
```

Making:

```
var myPicture = document.getElementById("picture1");
```

become:

```
var myPicture = document.getElementById(elID);
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are using table.insertRow(rowCount) unless you just want to keep expanding the table with every click.  I'd think you'd just want to get div1 by ID, then do the .innerHTML on that one.

Oh, and you might want to remove the onClick event of the element that you insert into the new div, and probably the element ID as well... maybe just better to just put an img tag in the div, and set the src attribute of the "enlarged" image you want to edit to be the src of the one that was clicked on.

Yes, looking at your code again, that's definitely what you want to do, generate a shell img tag, with its own width/height attributes, and just dynamically set the src attribute (right now, you are including the height/width attributes from the source img, so the size is always the same as the size is in the second table)

Comment: Yes, I could put the image in a div. I'll try to explain it to you again. What I want is that when I click on an image from my table, it will display that image in a div (let's forget the second table) with a bigger size. In this screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/34rvkgj/5 you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: And you only want one image to show in the "enlarged" section, right?
If that is so, you definitely don't want to use the table.insertRow.
What you want, is to put a shell image in that location.  Something like this:
<img id="EnlargedImg" src="" height="530px"; width="530px";>

Then

Comment: your addPictureToTable function would need to do this (after fetching the new element by ID):

bigImgElement.setAttribute("src",myPicture.getAttribute("src"));

Comment: Did this help, or did you ever figure out a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your end-application is ... but it seems that a cooler and more modern way of doing what you're doing is to use some sort of face-box jquery plugin..

http://wowslider.com/rq/jquery-picture-slider/
http://defunkt.io/facebox/

are somethings you can try!